# Environment "uat" does not exist in angular cli application

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to build a angular cli (version 5 ) application using the below command
ng build --env=uat --prod -bh /

I am getting the error "Environment "uat" does not exist."

I have the below lines in angular-cli.json

```
`   "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "uat": "environments/environment.uat.ts"
      }`
```

I have the file environments/environment.uat.ts created.

Can you please let me know what the issue might be?

Comment: try ng build --env=uat

Comment: same error with this command too

Comment: This should work. Are you sure they are in the correct folder? Can you run any other environment like dev or prod?

Comment: Yes for prod, it works fine

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with the contents of the `environment.uat.ts`? Just for testing purposes, maybe make a copy of the prod file and rename it to `environment.uat.ts` and then try to run the uat env and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

This caught me out and maybe worth a try....

"uat": "environments/environment.uat.ts" must be in .angular-cli.json (note the dot at the beginning of the file name)

I had  the line in another angular-cli.json file. So check you updated the correct json file you may have 2 in your project.

Comment: seems very strange, never heard of a dotted angular.json